# Array.prototype.filter callback must be a function REACT NATIVE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i used this code to fiter elements of array

```
const newList = this.state.ListCodeABarre.filter((cb) => cb !== CodeABarre);
    await this.setState({ ListCodeABarre: newList });
```

it works and remove the items correctly but it keeps showing this error

```
Array.prototype.filter callback must be a function
```

[image]

i also tryed using this code :

```
    var newList = this.state.ListCodeABarre.filter(function(cb) {
      return cb !== CodeABarre;
    });
    await this.setState({ ListCodeABarre: newList });
```

but still having the same error. and it's stuck with me it shows up all over the app not only when i opent that component

Comment: Are you sure that's the line where the exception comesfrom?

Comment: now i realised that it's not coming from array.filter ! i changed the code to this

Comment: var newList = []
    this.state.ListCodeABarre.map((cb) => {
      if (cb !== CodeABarre)
        newList.push(cb);
    }
    )

Comment: so now i'm not using array.filter anywhere in the app but it's still apearing !! how can this happend !